# asp.net masterpage preinit function

Tags: asp.net

i am writing a login page in asp.net c# not using login control.
i can create account and log in without problems as a user.

the pages that require login has a separate master page.

and i want to check if the user is logged in in masterpage page_preinit function

but the problem is that child page event functions are called before masterpage's so i could experience a problem like session expire in child page before i get to check it in master page. is there anyway around this?

ok found the event im looking for. second one on the list
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Are you using FormsAuthentication?  You shouldn't need to worry about this.  Authentication happens in the IIS pipeline before the Request is handed off to your Page object, and if the user's authentication fails, it will never get there, being redirected to the login page instead.

None of your PreInit code should be called by an unauthenticated user if the page is protected by FormsAuthentication.

Comment: no. pretty much wrong my own thing. i use session to store the user id. im getting a null reference error when sessin expire and session["userId"] no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many reasons why rolling-your-own authentication is a risky approach.  There are lots of corner cases.

Since you're storing the user ID in the Session object, then once the session expires, you can't access it any more; it doesn't matter if it's from the child page or the Master page.

Instead of using Session, it would be better to use cookies.  You could have a long life on the cookie itself, with the login expiration time encoded in the value of the cookie or kept in the database, keyed by the value of the cookie.  That way, the session could expire, but you would still be able to refresh it or take some other action, rather than just reporting an error.

Comment: i know sessions expire and i can check for that. the problem is where i can check for that. i want to be about to do it at masterpage page_load or page_preinit event. but the childpage events load first

Comment: You can be notified that a session has ended by registering for the `Session_End` event; however, those events are not delivered for *all* sessions that end, only some of them. You can also check to see if the session cookie is still there, although, again, that by itself isn't a 100% reliable indicator.  There's also the `Session.IsNewSession` flag, although it's only set if you also have a `Session_Start` event handler.  As I said: lots of corner cases.

Comment: In my experience, Session.IsNewSession is generally reliable; if what you say is true then something in the framework must subscribe to Session_Start, relieving you of the need to have to do it explicitly. We use IsNewSession together with a check of Request.Headers["Cookie"] and the existence of ASP.NET_SessionId to measure dropped sessions or session timeouts.